# SmartCapture form and Ampscript to add subscriber to multiple lists

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a microsite with a SmartCapture form for a new subscriber to select (via radio buttons) to receive one of 3 options. The choices are: `list-optionA`, `list-optionB`, both `list-optionA/optionB`.

A data extension and triggered Send have also been created for the on-submit "thank you" email.

Can anyone point me to the correct AMPScript syntax for adding a subscriber's email address to one or multiple subscriber lists.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example:

```
%%[

SET @Subscriber=CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@sub,"SubscriberKey", "[SubscriberKey here]")
SetObjectProperty(@Subscriber,"EmailAddress",[EmailAddress here])
Set @List = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
SetObjectProperty(@List,"ID","[List ID here]")
SetObjectProperty(@List,"Status","Active")
AddObjectArrayItem(@Subscriber,"Lists", @List)
InvokeUpdate(@Subscriber,@status_msg,@Update_err)

]%%
```

If you're wanting to use the SSJS functions, see the [List Server-Side JavaScript Functions](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/list_server_side_javascript_functions/).